# How to prevent a jumping picture when using tikz overlays

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following tikz picture in Beamer

```
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,matrix,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,system/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=3,minimum width=2cm,text width=1.8cm,text centered}]
    \node [system] (fe) {Feature Extraction};
    \node [system] (am) [right=of fe] {Acoustic Model};


    \draw[->] (fe) |- (am);
    \draw[<-,decorate,decoration={snake,pre length=6mm,segment length=2mm,amplitude=3mm}] (fe.west) -- ++(-2cm,0);

   \node<2-> [above=of fe.north] {Fast Fourier Tranform};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As you can see I add a node in a second slide. However, the whole picture will jump when this is added.

How can I prevent my picture from jumping?

Comment: When posting code, please also specify any particular packages or (as in this case) tikz libraries.  The `\documentclass{beamer} \usepackage{tikz}` was guessable, but I had to dig to figure out which tikzlibraries you were loading.  Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew Sorry for forgetting that, I'll add them still...

Comment: Phew!  And I didn't guess all of those!

Comment: Hmm, I'm now seeing that not all off them I'm actually using in this figure. Anyway, this were the libraries I included.

Comment: A general solution is available at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18704/86

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is due to the bounding box of the picture changing depending on whether or not that node is there.  There are several ways to resolve this:

1. Explicitly tell tikz what the bounding box is, thus ensuring that it is the same on both slides, using the `\useasboundingbox` or `\path[use as bounding box]` syntax.  Pros: you get exactly what you ask for.  Cons: you have to know exactly what to ask for.
2. Make the extra stuff always there, but only visible on the second slide.  There are a few ways of doing this; perhaps the simplest to wrap the whole node in a `\visible<2->{...}` rather than using `\node<2->`.  (It would be nice if tikz commands took *actions* as well as bare overlay specifications, but this doesn't seem to be the case.)  Another way is to put the node text in an overlay command, `{\visible<2->{Fast Fourier Transform}}`.  Yet another way would be to place an empty node (or a coordinate) at the desired spot and then put the node with text on the next slide:

   ```
   \coordinate [above=of fe.north] (pt);
   \node<2-> at (pt) {Fast Fourier Transform};
   ```

   Though this could still lead to a jump, you'd probably want to position the textual node so that it was below the coordinate.