# Align with colors and vspace using commands

Tags: math-mode, color, align, vspace

I'm trying to prepare notes for a class and am wanting to use an align environment in multiple areas but with a potential of two possibilities. Here's a mwe

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\usehidden{1}
\ifnum \usehidden=1
    \newcommand{\hidden}[2]{\vspace*{#1}}
\else
    \newcommand{\hidden}[2]{{\color{red}{#2}}}
\fi 

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        f(x) &= (x+1)^2\\
            &\hidden{7cm}{= (x+1)(x+1)\\
            &= x^2 + x + x + 1}\\
        &= x^2 + 2x + 1
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Basically the idea is that when I print the student's copy, `usehidden` is set to `1` and a vertical space is inserted for the students to fill in by hand. On my copy `usehidden` is set to `0` and the information is actually printed, but in red so I know that was the part that was excluded for the students.

So this works when I set `\usehidden{1}` but when `\usehidden{0}` I run into problems because of the color environment. Is there anyway to add color to multiple lines within an align environment?

Also, I noticed `vspace` isn't giving the appropriate size. Is there a way to make it give the right size?

The thing is, I want to use this style of format quite a few times. (I think I'm at around 50?) So anything that is generalizable and not only for this specific example would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use `\phantom{}` instead of guessing at what amount of space to leave:

[image]

### Notes:

- This does require that you use `\hidden` on *each* line that needs to be be hidden.

### References:

- Instead of `\color` I am using `\MathColor` from [Colored symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85033/4301)
  .

### Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85033/colored-symbols-in-latex
\newcommand*{\MathColor}{}
\def\MathColor#1#{\mathcoloraux{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mathcoloraux}[3]{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}

\providecommand\usehidden{0}
\ifnum \usehidden=1\relax
    \newcommand{\hidden}[1]{\phantom{#1}}
\else
    \newcommand{\hidden}[1]{{\MathColor{red}{#1}}}
\fi 

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    f(x) &= (x+1)^2 \\
         & \hidden{= (x+1)(x+1)} \\
         & \hidden{= x^2 + x + x + 1} \\
    &= x^2 + 2x + 1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\textcolor`, not `\color`.

Comment: Theoretically I'm aiming for a solution that allows me to group multiple lines together into one big bundle, but this might be a good alternative if I can't find a bundle version. 
@egreg why textcolor and not color?

Comment: @AramPapazian Because `\textcolor` is right and `\color` is wrong here.

Comment: @egreg: Corrected to use `\MathColor`.

Comment: @AramPapazian: See the link in the _References_ as to why not to use `\color` (or even `\textcolor`) in math mode.

Comment: @egreg ... That's not what I asked, but it's ok. I'll go look it up.

Comment: @PeterGrill Ok thanks for that =D I'll look into why not to use color using the link. I think I'm still preferring my second method because even though Phantom does do the job, I want there to actually be a bigger space for the students to be able to write in. Handwriting is bigger than typing ;) So I really need to be able to specify the heigh I want.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, it'd be nice to still get a solution using array, but until then I found the following workaround using array:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}


\newcommand\usehidden{0}

\ifnum \usehidden=1
    \newcommand{\hidden}[2]{&\vspace*{#1}\\}
\else
    \newcommand{\hidden}[2]{%
        \noalign{\gdef\mycolor{\color{red}}} %
        #2
        \noalign{\gdef\mycolor{}} 
    }
\fi 

\begin{document}
\def\mycolor{}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\mycolor}r}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\mycolor}c}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\mycolor}l}

\[  
    \begin{array}{RL}
        f(x) &= (x+1)^2\\
        \hidden{7cm}{&= (x+1)(x+1)\\
            &= x^2 + x + x + 1\\}
        &= x^2 + 2x + 1
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

The idea was taken from:
[Color a line in array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55517/color-a-line-in-array)

Comment: FYI, I was not able to get this to work as I thin it should.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I had forgotton to update the vspace parameter. Should be working as expected now.