# Highlight a column in equation or math environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, highlighting

While explaining the idea product of two negative numbers I wanted to highlight a vertical part of the display to emphasize on the factors that are being multiplied by:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{%
{\color{OrangeRed}#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    \left.\begin{array}{cc}
      -2\cdot \red{2}=& -4 \\
      -2\cdot \red{1}=& -2 \\
      -2\cdot \red{0}=& 0
    \end{array}\right\} \text{\small Product increases by 2 each time.}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

This gives:
[image]

So I chose to use a color but then I had also wanted to achieve something like the following:
[image]

I am not interested in the yellow red bordered box. What am looking for is an arrow pointing on the red numbers with a vertical border around  them as shown and the possibility of adding a node with text in the same format shown aligned with the word "Product".

> Edit

Can I use this method to achieve this:
[image]

Comment: Your update really should be a separate question as it is not longer about highlighting a column (makes it easier for others to find it and benefit from it).  But the answer is yes you can, see [How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717/how-to-draw-arrows-between-parts-of-an-equation-to-show-the-math-distributive-pr/35719#35719) for example.  If that does not solve your issue, please post a new question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To accomplish this task you can make use of the `tikzmark` macro. This solution allows to get:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{%
{\color{red}#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}

% to change colors
\newcommand{\fillcol}{white}
\newcommand{\bordercol}{red}

%% code by Andrew Stacey 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/background-coloring-with-overlay-specification-in-algorithm2e-beamer-package#51582

\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
     remember picture with id/.style={%
       remember picture,
       overlay,
       draw=\bordercol,
       save picture id=#1,
     },
     save picture id/.code={%
       \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
       \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
         \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
     },
     if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
       \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
         \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
       }{
         \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
       }
     }
   }

   \def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\def\tmk@labeldef#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\tmk@label{#1}%
  \def\tmk@def{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
  \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\tikzmarkin}[1]{%
      \tikz[remember picture with id=#1]
      \draw[line width=1pt,rectangle,rounded corners,fill=\fillcol]
      (pic cs:#1) ++(0.065,-0.15) rectangle (-0.05,0.32)
      ;}

\newcommand\tikzmarkend[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2] #1;}


\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    \left.\begin{array}{cc}
      -2\cdot \tikzmarkin{a}\red{2}=& -4 \\
      -2\cdot \red{1}=& -2 \\
      -2\cdot \red{0}\tikzmarkend{a}=& 0
    \end{array}\right\} \text{\small Product increases by 2 each time.}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Notice that you need to compile twice.

> **Explanation**

Inside the `tikzset` there is the definition of the style of the picture to be drawn (`remember picture with id`) then the definition and the writing on the the `.aux` of the id and position of the mark. Anyway, to get a better explanation, you can refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/13304. Finally, the commands that you need to use inside your document, `\tikzmarkin` and `\tikzmarkend` are defined.

> **EDIT**: insertion of the annotation

For this purpose I adopted the same trick of [Mark a pseudocode block and insert comments near it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57060/mark-a-pseudocode-block-and-insert-comments-near-it/57073#57073): the insertion of an anchor inside the `\tikzmarkin` macro to subsequently used it as reference to insert the annotation. What changes in the previous MWE?

In the preamble you should add:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % <= needed for some computations

\usepackage{lipsum} % <= needed to insert some text later
```

The `\tikzmarkin` should be improved as:

```
\newcommand{\tikzmarkin}[1]{%
      \tikz[remember picture with id=#1]
      \draw[line width=1pt,rectangle,rounded corners,fill=\fillcol]
      (pic cs:#1) ++(0.065,-0.15) rectangle (-0.05,0.32) node [anchor=base] (#1){}
      ;}
```

where the relevant new part is just `node [anchor=base] (#1){}`.

Finally, the `document`:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    \left.\begin{array}{cc}
      -2\cdot \tikzmarkin{a}\red{2}=& -4 \\
      -2\cdot \red{1}=& -2 \\
      -2\cdot \red{0}\tikzmarkend{a}=& 0
    \end{array}\right\} \text{\small Product increases by 2 each time.}
    \end{equation*}

    % To insert the annotation
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \coordinate (aa) at ($(a)+(1.825,-1.65)$); % <= adjust this parameter to move the position of the annotation 
        \node[align=left,right] at (aa) {\small{Annotation}};
        \path[-latex,red,draw] (aa) -| ($(a)+(0.15,-1.3)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \linebreak

    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The last part is the one needed to insert the annotation: first I defined a coordinate where to insert it based on the anchor previously saved (to accomplish this, it is important that the `tikzpicture` has as options `remember picture,overlay`). The last command:

```
\path[-latex,red,draw] (aa) -| ($(a)+(0.15,-1.3)$);
```

draws the arrow: the starting point is the coordinate of the annotation and the final point should be computed knowing that the reference anchor `a` is placed on the top left of the red rectangle.

This will lead to:

[image]

One final remark: I think should be better to insert a `\linebreak` after the `tikzpicture` to avoid that the annotation will be placed too nearly the subsequent text.

Comment: I don't like to copy and paste rather read and learn from your code. I would appreciate if you could explain within your answer some of steps you took to achieve the result. Your answer seems elaborate yet still missing the arrow point with the description.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my answer to insert an explanation; for what concern the arrow and the description, I've read that you were not interested in the yellow red bordered box. Do you want the description in the same position of the yellow red box?

Comment: I've edited my answer to accomplish the missing part. :)

Comment: One small suggestion: because you're using `remember picture with id` in the `\tikzmarkin`, you actually are remembering the same id twice which probably isn't a good habit to get into (doesn't affect things here, but could in other situations).  One option is for the `\tikzmarkin` simply to be `remember picture,overlay` since you never need to refer to it again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've verified it by changing simply the `\tikzmarkin` code into: `\newcommand{\tikzmarkin}[1]{%
   \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw[line width=1pt,rectangle,rounded corners,fill=\fillcol, draw=\bordercol]
      (pic cs:#1) ++(0.065,-0.15) rectangle (-0.05,0.32) node [anchor=base] (#1){}
      ;}` and the final output is still equal. What changes is the `.aux` file because the {a} is unique.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I update my question. My concern is the curved arrow line and how to get pointing to the number 3 and 2 with respective labels. I didnt want to ask another question as it is similar to what is happening here.