# Beamer - Source code highlighting/annotation tips

Tags: beamer, highlighting

How can I highlight and annotate source code in a beamer presentation like [this one](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2012/blob/master/mon/concurrency.pdf?raw=true)? For example, consider the following image from that .pdf file:

[image]

It looks to me that above presentation is made with beamer...

Comment: This presentation was created using Apple's keynote (check the properties of the PDF), but that's beside the point.
I have not seen a package to do this, but a combination of [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) for the display of the source code (you use it almost the same as you would the verbatim environment) and [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) to draw the boxes

Comment: For example [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57060/3235). I'm pretty sure @ClaudioFiandrino can give you an example with TikZ libraries `shapes.callouts` and `shadows`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @percusse suggested in his comment, I'll provide you a solution similar to [Mark a pseudocode block and insert comments near it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57060/mark-a-pseudocode-block-and-insert-comments-near-it), that adopts Daniel's method illustrated in [Issues and potentiality of the tikzmark macro: dynamic box adaptation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/issues-and-potentiality-of-the-tikzmark-macro-dynamic-box-adaptation/57798#57798) and in [Highlight text in code listing while also keeping syntax highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/highlight-text-in-code-listing-while-also-keeping-syntax-highlighting/49309#49309). The basic idea is to `mark` the text highlighted to subsequently use the marker as reference to insert the annotation. This has been done by giving a name to the node used for the highlighting instead of let this job to the `\tikzmark` macro.

```
\newcommand{\bt@HL@box}[2][]{%
  \tikz[#1]{%
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfpoint{\wd #2}{\ht #2}}%
    \pgfusepath{use as bounding box}%
    \node[anchor=base west,rounded corners, fill=green!30,outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0.2em, inner ysep=0.1em,  #1](a\theimage){\usebox{#2}};
  }%
   %\tikzmark{a\theimage} <= can be used, but it leads to a spacing problem
   % the best approach is to name the previous node with (a\theimage)
 \stepcounter{image}
}
```

The solution leads to:

[image]

thanks to this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts,shadows, calc}
\usepackage{listings}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\tikzset{note/.style={rectangle callout, rounded corners,fill=gray!20,drop shadow,font=\footnotesize}}    

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}    

\newcounter{image}
\setcounter{image}{1}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{btHighlight}[1][]
{\begingroup\tikzset{bt@Highlight@par/.style={#1}}\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
{\end{lrbox}\bt@HL@box[bt@Highlight@par]{\@tempboxa}\endgroup}

\newcommand\btHL[1][]{%
  \begin{btHighlight}[#1]\bgroup\aftergroup\bt@HL@endenv%
}
\def\bt@HL@endenv{%
  \end{btHighlight}%   
  \egroup
}
\newcommand{\bt@HL@box}[2][]{%
  \tikz[#1]{%
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfpoint{\wd #2}{\ht #2}}%
    \pgfusepath{use as bounding box}%
    \node[anchor=base west,rounded corners, fill=green!30,outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0.2em, inner ysep=0.1em,  #1](a\theimage){\usebox{#2}};
  }%
   %\tikzmark{a\theimage} <= can be used, but it leads to a spacing problem
   % the best approach is to name the previous node with (a\theimage)
 \stepcounter{image}
}
\makeatother


\lstset{language=C++,
                basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
                keywordstyle=\footnotesize\color{blue}\ttfamily,
                moredelim=**[is][\btHL]{`}{`},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Better approach}
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <future>
std::map<std::string,std::string> french
{{"hello","bonjour"},{"world","tout le monde"}};
int main()
{
std::string greet=french["hello"];
auto f=std::async(`[&]{std::cout << greet <<", ";}`);
`std::string audience=french["word"];`
f.get();
std::cout<<audience<<std::endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}
% To insert the annotation
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
% first annotation
\coordinate (aa) at ($(a1)+(5,5)$); % <= adjust this parameter to move the position of the annotation 
\node[note,draw,callout relative pointer={($(aa)-(9,3.35)$)},right] at (aa) {time consuming I/O};

%second annotation
\coordinate (bb) at ($(a2)+(3.25,3.25)$); % <= adjust this parameter to move the position of the annotation 
\node[note,draw,callout relative pointer={($(bb)-(7,1.1)$)},right] at (bb) {next lookup};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> **Remarks**

- This has been the first time I used `callouts` thus maybe there are better approaches than mine to position pointers.
- The code has been developed by automatically `marking` the position of the highlighting box; when you use after the `tikzpicture` to position nodes, you should refer to markers as `(a1), (a2)` and so on; `(a1)` should be the position of the first code highlighted.
- To highlight a piece of code, two new delimiters are defined and are ` ` . You can redefine yours by changing this line of code: `moredelim=**[is][\btHL]{new delim}{new delim}` where, of course, `new delim` should be your new delimiter character.

Comment: Actually Daniel did almost 97.5% of the job. ;) His method is very powerful and immediate: I just placed a marker to used it later on. :)