# Counting lines and making calculations

Tags: calculations, emphasis

[This](https://gist.github.com/548097) code snippet provides a way to highlight lines in a listings environment. If you consider the following line, though:

```
\emphline{1-6} {7} {8-15} {potencia.f95}
```

You'll notice how the #1 and the #3 parameters could be deducted from #2. To do so, one would need to:

- know the total number of lines of the `potencia.f95` file;
- perform subtractions and additions in LaTeX

Would it be possible to do the above, translating the command into one which could be used as:

```
\emphline{7}{potencia.f95}
```

Or even, if one would like to highlight an entire section:

```
\emphline{7-12}{potencia.f95}
```

Comment: To highlight lines of code you can adopt an approach like [Hightlight an XML code beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62633/hightlight-an-xml-code-beamer/62650#62650) or also [Highlight text in code listing while also keeping syntax highlighting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/highlight-text-in-code-listing-while-also-keeping-syntax-highlighting/49309#49309).

Comment: That requires to edit the source code to include style information. I need to preserve the original source code, which is embedded from an external file.

Comment: I see your point. My consideration has been done taking into account that in a presentation it's not possible to show too many lines of code, therefore the cost of editing more or less a snippet of 20 lines is not so high.

Comment: I'm not using this in a beamer presentation. I'm just re-using the idea in a generic doc, when I need to include pages of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I came out with the following, simple, solution. Basically, I use a counter to track the line number:

```
\newcounter{linenumber}
...
\setcounter{linenumber}{#1}
\addtocounter{linenumber}{-1}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={1-\value{linenumber}}]{#2}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={#1-#1},style=highlight,firstnumber=last]{#2}
\addtocounter{linenumber}{2}
\lstinputlisting[firstline=\the\value{linenumber},firstnumber=last]{#2}
```

Please note how you need to use `\the` when specifying the `firstline`. This is not needed in the `linerange` case.