# Generating a box inside algorithm in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, algorithms

I would like to create two boxes (or two frames) and one arrow which goes from the center of right side of one box and do half a circle and point on the other box.

Below is an example of code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $y \leftarrow 1$
% Start box 1
\If{$n < 0$}
\State $X \leftarrow 1 / x$
\State $N \leftarrow -n$
\Else
\State $X \leftarrow x$
\State $N \leftarrow n$
\EndIf
%End box 1
%Start box 2
\While{$N \neq 0$}
\If{$N$ is even}
\State $X \leftarrow X \times X$
\State $N \leftarrow N / 2$
\Else[$N$ is odd]
\State $y \leftarrow y \times X$
\State $N \leftarrow N - 1$
\EndIf
\EndWhile
% End box 2
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How could I create a box around the first `\If` condition (until `\EndIf`) and around while condition and then an arrow from the center of the right side of of the "if condition" to the "while condition" box?

Comment: I think you could refer to [Mark a pseudocode block and insert comments near it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57060/mark-a-pseudocode-block-and-insert-comments-near-it/57073#57073) as starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility, placing marks and then using the marks to draw the boxes and the arrow:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,intersections}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \coordinate (#1);}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}
\State\tikzmark{start1} $y \leftarrow 1$
% Start box 1
\If{$n < 0$}
\State $X \leftarrow 1 / x$
\State $N \leftarrow -n$
\Else
\State $X \leftarrow x$
\State $N \leftarrow n$
\EndIf\tikzmark{end1}
%End box 1
%Start box 2
\Statex\vskip-2.2ex
\tikzmark{start2}\While{$N \neq 0$}
\If{$N$ is even}
\State $X \leftarrow X \times X$
\State $N \leftarrow N / 2$
\Else[$N$ is odd]
\State $y \leftarrow y \times X$
\State $N \leftarrow N - 1$
\EndIf
\EndWhile\tikzmark{end2}
% End box 2
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[orange] ( $ (start1) + (-2pt,-2pt) $ ) rectangle ( $ (end1) + (1.3,-2pt) $ );
\draw[orange] ( $ (start2) + (-2pt,-2pt) $ ) rectangle ( $ (end2) + (1.8,-2pt) $ );
\draw[orange,-latex] let \p1=(start1), \p2=(end1), \p3=(start2), \p4=(end2) 
  in ( $ (\x2,0.5*\y1+0.5*\y2) + (1.3,0) $ ) to[out=0,in=0] ( $ (\x4,0.5*\y3+0.5*\y4) + (1.8,0) $ );
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]