# Frame for pieces of algorithms

Tags: algorithm2e, decorations

I would like to put frames around pieces of algorithms like in the following picture. If the background of the rectangle can be changed, it would be nice.

[image]

Here is the LaTeX code used for the algorithm.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Le crible d'Eratosthène}

    \KwData{la liste $L$ des naturels compris de $2$ à $N$.}
    \KwResult{la liste $P$ des nombres premiers compris entre $2$ et $N$.}
    \BlankLine
    \For{$i = 2$ \KwTo $N$}{
        \If{$i$ n'est pas barré dans la liste $L$}{
            Barrer dans la liste $L$ les mutltiples $ki$ où $k \geq 2$.
        }
    }
    \Return{la liste $P$ des nombres non barrés.}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a couple of answers that you can use (exploiting both a `\tikzmark` solution): [Mark a pseudocode block and insert comments near it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57060/mark-a-pseudocode-block-and-insert-comments-near-it) and [Background coloring with overlay specification in algorithm2e + beamer package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/background-coloring-with-overlay-specification-in-algorithm2e-beamer-package)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A job for `\tikzmark`; the `\MyBox` command allows to draw the colored frame; the syntax is

```
\MyBox[<vertical offset>]{<mark>}{<mark>}{<color>}
```

An example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}

% code by Andrew Stacey
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/3954    
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  remember picture with id/.style={%
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    save picture id=#1,
  },
  save picture id/.code={%
    \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
    \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
      \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
  },
  if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
    }{
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    }
  }
}

\def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\def\tmk@labeldef#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\tmk@label{#1}%
  \def\tmk@def{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
  \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2] #1;}
\makeatother
% end of code by Andrew Stacey

\newcommand\MyBox[4][-1ex]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,pin distance=0cm]
  {\draw[draw=#4,line width=1pt,fill=#4!20,rectangle,rounded corners]
( $ (pic cs:#2) + (-1ex,2ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (1ex,#1) $ );
}
}

\begin{document}

\MyBox{starta}{enda}{blue}
\MyBox[-3ex]{startb}{endb}{red}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Le crible d'Eratosthène}

    \tikzmark{starta}\KwData{la liste $L$ des naturels compris de $2$ à $N$.}
    \KwResult{la liste $P$ des nombres premiers compris entre $2$ et $N$.\tikzmark{enda}}
    \BlankLine
    \For{$i = 2$ \KwTo $N$}{
        \tikzmark{startb}\If{$i$ n'est pas barré dans la liste $L$}{
            Barrer dans la liste $L$ les mutltiples $ki$ où $k \geq 2$.\tikzmark{endb}
        }
    }
    \Return{la liste $P$ des nombres non barrés.}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool ! Can I focus several pieces in the same algorithm ? In my example it could be the `IF` block and the `DATA-RESULT` block.

Comment: @projetmbc Sure; simply use `\tikzmark` to place marks at the proper locations and then `\MyBox` to draw the box between the marks.

Comment: Last question. Can I use different colors ?

Comment: @projetmbc answer updated.