# Decorate minted listing inside a tcolorobox [Merly done...]

Tags: tikz-pgf, minted, decorations, tcblisting

I would like to decorate some listings just for pedagogical reasons.

[image]

Here is a starting code where I can draw a line but I still fail to produce a frame. How can I do that ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[skins, many, minted, breakable, hooks]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}


\makeatletter

% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124688/6880

\newcommand{\mynewminted}[3]{%
    \newminted[#1]{#2}{#3}%
    \tcbset{myminted/#1/.style = {
        minted language = #2, 
        minted options  = {#3}
    }}
}


\newcommand{\create@new@coding@env@title}[4]{%
    \mynewminted{for-coding-#1}{python}{escapeinside=||}

    \newtcblisting[]{coding-#1}[2][1]{%
        listing only,
        width        = ##1\linewidth,
        title        = ##2,
        myminted/for-coding-python,
    }
}

\create@new@coding@env@title{python}{\Large\faPython}{2mm}{1.8mm}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{coding-python}{Basic loop
Python}
|\tikzmark{topleft}|def oneloop(n):            |\tikzmark{topright}|
    for i in range(n):
        print(i**2)        |\tikzmark{downright}|

print(oneloop(n))
\end{coding-python}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikz[remember picture] \draw[overlay, red] (pic cs:topright) -- (pic cs:downright);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that could help other people. **I am not the clever man who solves my issue** because I use the following old post of mine : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78566/6880. The output looks like in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[skins, many, minted, breakable, hooks]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,fit}


\makeatletter

% Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/3954

\newcommand\myframe[4][-1ex]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay,pin distance=0cm]{
    \draw[draw=#4,line width=1pt,fill=#4!20,rectangle,rounded corners, opacity=0.2]
    ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (-1ex,2ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (1ex,#1) $ );
    \draw[draw=#4,line width=1pt,rectangle,rounded corners, opacity=1]
    ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (-1ex,2ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (1ex,#1) $ );
}

% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124688/6880

\newcommand{\mynewminted}[3]{%
    \newminted[#1]{#2}{#3}%
    \tcbset{myminted/#1/.style = {
        minted language = #2, 
        minted options  = {#3}
    }}
}


\newcommand{\create@new@coding@env@title}[4]{%
    \mynewminted{for-coding-#1}{python}{escapeinside=||}

    \newtcblisting[]{coding-#1}[2][1]{%
        listing only,
        width        = ##1\linewidth,
        title        = ##2,
        myminted/for-coding-python,
    }
}

\create@new@coding@env@title{python}{\Large\faPython}{2mm}{1.8mm}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{coding-python}{Basic loop
Python}
|\tikzmark{topleft}|def oneloop(n):            
    for i in range(n):
        print(i**2)   |\tikzmark{downright}|

print(oneloop(n))
\end{coding-python}

\myframe[-2ex]{topleft}{downright}{red}

\end{document}
```