# Understanding a new command and editing it

Tags: beamer, macros

I'm trying to highlight some pseudocode lines, and I'm using this solution  [pseudocode block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57060/mark-a-pseudocode-block-and-insert-comments-near-it). However, I've not understood the following new command:

```
\newcommand{\fillcol}{green!20}
\newcommand<>{\boxto}[1]{
\only#2{
    \tikz[remember picture with id=#1]
    \draw[line width=1pt,fill=\fillcol,rectangle,rounded corners]
    (pic cs:#1) ++(8.2,-.1) rectangle (-3.4,-.1);
    }
}
```

What's mean the symbols `<>` in front of `\newcommand`?

Moreover, I'd like to pass the color to fill the rectangle as parameter for
the `\boxto` command. In the posted solution, the color is defined as a command `\fillcol` How to do this change? Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: `<>` is beamer class syntax which allows blocks of text to appear in different layers specified by  for example `<2>`

Comment: If you don't use `beamer`  you can drop `<>` and **must** drop `\only#2`.

Comment: I'm using a beamer template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for quickness: I did not copy over unnecessary code from the linked question, i.e. I disabled the `pic` coordinate system and the `tikz remember picture with id=#1` style.

The `beamer` class adds a new version of `\newcommand`, making it possible to generate commands with overlay specification, with

```
\newcommand<>{\cmdname}[number of args]{%...

% rest of code
}
```

Important to know is that the overlay specification is inside and that the command in fact has one more argument than specified, i.e. in the example, there are 3 arguments. The third one is meant for the overlay, so the last argument is always 'hidden', but can be accessed.

Please note, that the pointed brackets `<1>` belong to the last argument, that's how `\only#3` works then.

For more on this see section 9.6 of the current beamer documentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\fillcol}{green!20}
\newcommand<>{\boxto}[2]{
\only#3{%
  \tikz%[remember picture with id=#1]
  \draw[line width=1pt,fill=#2,rectangle,rounded corners] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
  }%
}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Foo frame}
\boxto<1>{1}{green}

\boxto<2>{1}{red}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works almost perfectly. There is just one problem: when I use `\boxto<2>{1}{red}` the second box is not displayed. So, I must to call `\boxto<1>{1}{green}` and `\boxto<1>{1}{red}`. In this case, the two boxes are displayed. Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: @tnas a command with `<2>` will not be displayed originally, that is the meaning of the overlay, it will appear in the second layer if you advance the presentation.

Comment: @tnas: My example was simplified because I did not want to copy the code from the linked question just in order to show how the `<>` syntax works for `beamer`'s `\newcommand`