# How to add label on arc of this graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In a previous question I enjoyed a beautifull graph [How improve tikZ graphs arrows rendering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71230/how-improve-tikz-graphs-arrows-rendering)

How can I add label on arcs produced by:

```
\draw[arrow] (NodeName)--(OtherNodeName);
```

Comment: Do you mean "edge" instead of "arc"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply add a `node` before the semi colon:

[image]

### References:

- To select the position of the node label see [Moving a label along the path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29712/moving-a-label-along-the-path/29713#29713)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->, ultra thick, blue] (0,0)--(1,2) node [pos=0.5, above, red, sloped] {label};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```