# How to underline in math mode with ampersand anchor?

Tags: math-mode, align, ampersand

When I use the ampersand & in align for positioning I loose the underline function. Is there a (simple) way of underlining the last math line completely?

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{H} (c, K, \lambda, t) &= \frac{c^{1-\frac{1}{\sigma} } -1}{1 - \frac{1}{\sigma}} + \lambda \cdot \left(  r \cdot K + w \cdot L_Y + \Pi_x \cdot A - c \cdot L \right) \\
    \Leftrightarrow \frac{\dot c}{c} &= \sigma \cdot \left( r - \rho - n \right) \tag{25}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Example:

[image]

Comment: some possibilities here: [Underlining an equation in an align block](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78929/579)

Answer (score 4):

You can underline the whole equation or colour it..... using `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[theorems,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\underlined}[1][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,tcbox raise base,
enhanced jigsaw,arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt,colback=white,colframe=black,
#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\underlined]{align}
    \mathcal{H} (c, K, \lambda, t) &= \frac{c^{1-\frac{1}{\sigma} } -1}{1 - \frac{1}{\sigma}} + \lambda \cdot \left(  r \cdot K + w \cdot L_Y + \Pi_x \cdot A - c \cdot L \right) \notag\\
    \Leftrightarrow \frac{\dot c}{c} &= \sigma \cdot \left( r - \rho - n \right)
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But my MWE was just a code snippet. This box just underlines the last line of math-environment? Would be great to give underline to any line also within the align or empheq.

Comment: @Mac Yes only the last line.  If you want every line, then you have to put them in separate environments.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? After a lot of phantoms, looks right.

```
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{H} (c, K, \lambda, t) &= \frac{c^{1-\frac{1}{\sigma} } -1}{1 - \frac{1}{\sigma}} + \lambda \cdot \left(  r \cdot K + w \cdot L_Y + \Pi_x \cdot A - c \cdot L \right) \\
\rlap{%
 \underline{%
  \vphantom{$\displaystyle\frac{\dot c}{c}$}%
  \hphantom{$\Leftrightarrow \frac{\dot c}{c} = \sigma \cdot \left( r - \rho - n \right)$}%
 }%
}%
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\dot c}{c} &= \sigma \cdot \left( r - \rho - n \right) 
\tag{25}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a way that gives a end-to-end underline. Even under the equation sign.