# Underline in flalign

Tags: underline

For some reason, `\underline` doesn't work in `\begin{flalign*}`. I have a fragment of an equation which ends like

```
\begin{flalign*}
t&=10
\end{flalign*}
```

and I want to underline the last equation

```
\begin{flalign*}
\underline{t&=10}
\end{flalign*}
```

and I'm getting an error about a missing } which is not missing. Why?

inb4: yes, I know I can underline both sides of the equation, that's not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you cannot enclose the alignment point `&` within the `\underline`. Quick fix: overprint the line first.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\mathrlap{\underline{\phantom{t=10}}}t&=10 \\
t &= 10
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`mathtools` is an extension to `amsmath` (which is automatically loaded) and provides `\mathrlap`. You can obtain the same without `mathtools` with e.g.

```
\begin{flalign*}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\underline{$\phantom{t=10}$}}t&=10 \\
t &= 10
\end{flalign*}
```

or (more plain TeX)

```
\begin{flalign*}
\rlap{\underline{$\phantom{t=10}$}}t&=10 \\
t &= 10
\end{flalign*}
```

but I find the code hard to read. Furthermore, `\mathrlap` will always use the correct math style; not an issue in this specific case but it will be if you try to underline more complicated expressions.

Other ways are shown in [Underlining an equation in an align block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78929/82917).

Comment: Neither of these really look nice, I find it baffling that the most basic of formatting options sometime srequire reinventing the wheel in this supposedly amazing language. But thanks.