# Frames around few line of code in a algorithm

Tags: algorithms, framed

I want to put a box around lines of code and to add comments inside the box.

This is what I want it to achieve:
[image]

This is the example of code I am  using for the algorithm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{subcaption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*{algorithm}
\renewcommand\thesubalgorithm{\thetable\alph{subalgorithm}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{alglabel}{Alg.~#2}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}%
\begin{subalgorithm}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}%\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}%\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$%\Comment{The gcd is b}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{algo1}
\end{subalgorithm}%
\begin{subalgorithm}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}%\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}%\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$%\Comment{The gcd is b}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{algo2}
\end{subalgorithm}
\captionsetup{labelformat=alglabel}
\caption{Two algorithms}%
\label{tab:1}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I've edited your question to add a picture of what you currently have. Could you perhaps draw onto the picture somehow, to show exactly what you want? It's a little hard to tell from your textual description.

Comment: I think [Background coloring with overlay specification in algorithm2e + beamer package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51582/13304) shall give you all the hints to proceed.

Answer (score 7):

Here's some code to get you started. The idea is to use the ubiquitous `\tikzmark` to place some marks at the appropriate locations, and then to draw the boxes with the text; I used the `fit` library for this purpose:

The \Textbox command has two optional arguments and three mandatory ones:

```
\Textbox[<length1>][<length2>]{<name1>}{<name2>}{<text>}
```

where `<length1>` specifies the additional width of the box (default=`2.5cm`); `<length2>` controls the width of the box where the text will be typeset (default=`2cm`); `<name1>` and `<name2>` are previously set marks that will be used to draw the box, and `<text>` is the text that will be typeset (adjust the settings according to your needs).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{twoopt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner xsep=0pt] (#1) {};}
\newcommandtwoopt\Textbox[5][2.5cm][2cm]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \coordinate (aux) at ([xshift=#1]#4);
  \node[inner ysep=3pt,yshift=0.6ex,draw=red,thick,
    fit=(#3) (aux),baseline] 
    (box) {};
  \node[text width=#2,anchor=north east,
    font=\sffamily\footnotesize,align=right] 
    at (box.north east) {#5};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*{algorithm}
\renewcommand\thesubalgorithm{\thetable\alph{subalgorithm}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{alglabel}{Alg.~#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}%
\begin{subalgorithm}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}%\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}%\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State\tikzmark{start1}$b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$\tikzmark{end1}
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$%\Comment{The gcd is b}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{algo1}
\end{subalgorithm}%
\begin{subalgorithm}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}%\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State\tikzmark{start2}$r\gets a\bmod b$\tikzmark{end2}
    \While{$r\not=0$}%\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State\tikzmark{start3}$a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$\tikzmark{end3}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State\tikzmark{start4}\textbf{return} $b$\tikzmark{end4}%\Comment{The gcd is b}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{algo2}
\end{subalgorithm}
\captionsetup{labelformat=alglabel}
\caption{Two algorithms}%
\label{tab:1}%
\Textbox{start1}{end1}{piece of code 1}
\Textbox{start2}{end2}{piece of code 2}
\Textbox[3cm]{start3}{end3}{piece of code 3}
\Textbox{start4}{end4}{piece of code 4}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Remark:

Since `\tikzmark` is being used and some coordinate calculations are involved, the code needs three runs to produce the correct output.