# Box around lines of algpseudocode with \tikzmark

Tags: tikzmark, algpseudocode

I use the algpseudocode package to write code and I would like to draw boxes around some lines of the code. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116691/) gets pretty close to what I want. The idea is to mark the first and last line of code with `\tikzmark` and then draw a box around the obtained coordinates. The problem with this approach is that it only works for lines starting with `\State`. For example when I use `\tikzmark` after an if-statement, it does not mark the beginning of the line but some position farther right.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,tikzmark}

\newcommand\drawCodeBox[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \coordinate (start) at ([yshift=1.7ex]pic cs:#1);
        \coordinate (end) at ([yshift=-0.3ex]pic cs:#2);
        \node[inner sep=2pt,draw=red,fit=(start) (end)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \State \tikzmark{s1}%
    $x \gets 0$\tikzmark{e1}
    \drawCodeBox{s1}{e1}
    \State $y \gets 1$
    \If{$x = y$}\tikzmark{s2}
        \State PANIC
    \EndIf\tikzmark{e2}
    \drawCodeBox{s2}{e2}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image: What I get]

The desired result is:

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Werner's comment on his answer, I have defined `\BoxedState`, `\BoxedIf`, `\BoxedWhile`, etc., which set a mark at the beginning of the line and draw a box. The optional argument sets the style of the box. The command `\EndBox` sets the lower end of the box, `\SetBoxEast` can be used at the end of the longest line in the box to set the right end. If the last line is the longest one, `\SetBoxEast` can be ommited.

The counter `tmkcount` is used to keep the marks unique. The box is drawn before its contents, so it can be filled. Limitations include:

- The box does not adapt to very high first lines.
- It is assumed that no line within the box start further left than the first one.

### Code and example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,tikzmark}

\newcounter{tmkcount}
\tikzset{%
    tikzmark suffix={-\thetmkcount},%
    defaultCodeBox/.style={draw=red}%
}

\newcommand{\drawCodeBox}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \coordinate (start) at ([yshift=1.4ex]pic cs:#2);
        \coordinate (middle) at (pic cs:#3);
        \coordinate (end) at ([yshift=-0.2ex]pic cs:#4);
        \node[inner sep=2pt,#1,fit=(start) (middle) (end)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\BeginBox}[1]{%
    \drawCodeBox{#1}{beginCB}{middleCB}{endCB}%
    \tikzmark{beginCB}\tikzmark{middleCB}%
}

\newcommand{\SetBoxEast}{%
    \unskip%
    \tikzmark{middleCB}%
}

\newcommand{\EndBox}{%
    \unskip%
    \tikzmark{endCB}%
    \stepcounter{tmkcount}%
}

\newcommand{\BoxedState}[1][defaultCodeBox]{\State\BeginBox{#1}\ignorespaces}

\algdef{S}[WHILE]{BoxedWhile}[2][defaultCodeBox]{\BeginBox{#1}\algorithmicwhile\ #2\ \algorithmicdo}%
\algdef{S}[FOR]{BoxedFor}[2][defaultCodeBox]{\BeginBox{#1}\algorithmicfor\ #2\ \algorithmicdo}%
\algdef{S}[FOR]{BoxedForAll}[2][defaultCodeBox]{\BeginBox{#1}\algorithmicforall\ #2\ \algorithmicdo}%
\algdef{S}[LOOP]{BoxedLoop}[1][defaultCodeBox]{\BeginBox{#1}\algorithmicloop}%
\algdef{S}[REPEAT]{BoxedRepeat}[1][defaultCodeBox]{\BeginBox{#1}\algorithmicrepeat}%
\algdef{S}[IF]{BoxedIf}[2][defaultCodeBox]{\BeginBox{#1}\algorithmicif\ #2\ \algorithmicthen}%
\algdef{C}[IF]{IF}{BoxedElsIf}[2][defaultCodeBox]{\BeginBox{#1}\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif\ #2\ \algorithmicthen}%
\algdef{Ce}[ELSE]{IF}{BoxedElse}{EndIf}[1][defaultCodeBox]{\BeginBox{#1}\algorithmicelse}%


\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \BoxedState $x \gets 0$
    \State $y \gets x + 1$\EndBox
    \If{$x < y$}
        \State $x \gets x + 1$
    \BoxedElse[fill=yellow]
        \State do some complicated stuff\SetBoxEast
        \State $y \gets y + 1$\EndBox
    \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

To stick to your `\drawCodeBox` macro, you'll have to *position* the `\tikzmark`s at the appropriate location. We can move `\tikzmark{e2}` to the right by placing it inside a `\makebox[0pt][r]` and explicitly stacking it (horizontally) with exactly what `\EndIf` sets (`\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,tikzmark}

\newcommand\drawCodeBox[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (start) at ([yshift=1.7ex]pic cs:#1);
    \coordinate (end) at ([yshift=-0.3ex]pic cs:#2);
    \node[inner sep=2pt,draw=red,fit=(start) (end)] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
  \State \tikzmark{s1}%
  $x \gets 0$\tikzmark{e1}
  \drawCodeBox{s1}{e1}
  \State $y \gets 1$
  \If{$x = y$}\tikzmark{s2}
    \State PANIC
  \EndIf\makebox[0pt][r]{\tikzmark{e2}\phantom{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}}
  \drawCodeBox{s2}{e2}
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Is there a more generic way to get the length of the current line than looking up `\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif` etc.? Ideally, one could then create a macro `\tikzmarkLeft` that automatically positions the mark at the left of the current line.

Comment: @ChristianMatt: You could probably leave a `\tikzmark{lmargin}` against the `l`eft `margin`, and then calculate the difference between a placed `\tikzmarkLeft{here}` and `lmargin` using some details in [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33703/5764). Alternative, use the page coordinates. I'm too unfamiliar with `tikz` to know how to do that...

Comment: ...perhaps a better option would be to define a `\tikzmarkEndIf{<mark>}` macro that sets a mark just before setting `\algorithmicend`. That way you don't have to know anything about the current indentation.