# Multiline box over subset of aligned equations

Tags: equations, align

I have a multilined equation which is aligned as follows: (schematically)

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{Equ} &\equiv \text{first line of RHS} \;+\nonumber \\
 & \phantom{=}+\;\text{second line of RHS}\nonumber \\
 & =\text{third line of RHS} \; +\nonumber \\
 & \phantom{=} +\; \text{fourth line of RHS} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

What I'd like to achieve is a multiline box over *only* the third and fourth lines as follows:

[image]

I have tried using the \boxed{} function but this wouldn't work over multiple lines.  Note: I would prefer *not* to box the entire four lines in this case.

Is this possible and, if so, how is it done?

**Edit: (subsequent to answer by Bernard)** I am having 2 difficulties implementing the `pstricks` solution: 1) The numbering seems to start over outside the `postscript` environment.  2) Equation references `\eqref{}` don't seem to work with `\label{}` inside the `postscript`.  See output and MWE below:

[image: problem]

```
\documentclass[english, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\begin{align}
\text{Equ} & \equiv \text{first line of RHS} +{} \\
                         & =+\;\text{second line of RHS} \\
\pnode[-0.6em, 2.5ex]{A} & =\text{third line of RHS} + {} \\
                         & = +\; \text{fourth line of RHS}   \pnode[0.8em, -1.5ex]{B}   \label{Equ1}
\end{align}
\psframe[linejoin=1, linecolor=black](A)(B)
\end{postscript}

\begin{align}
\text{Equ2} &= \text{first line of RHS}\\
&= \text {second line of RHS}\label{Equ2}
\end{align}

Reference to Equ1: \eqref{Equ1}.  Reference to Equ2: \eqref{Equ2}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shamelessly borrowed from Werner at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358675/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{Equ} &\equiv \text{first line of RHS} \nonumber \\
 &\quad + \text{second line of RHS} \nonumber \\
 \tikzmark{start1} &=\text{third line of RHS} \nonumber \\
 &\quad + \text{fourth line of RHS} \tikzmark{end1}
\end{align}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \coordinate (start) at ([yshift=1.7ex]pic cs:start1);
  \coordinate (end) at ([yshift=-0.3ex]pic cs:end1);
  \node[inner sep=2pt,draw=red,fit=(start) (end)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is easy with `pstricks`: place an empty node at the beginning of the third row, another empty node at the end of the fourth row, and draw the frame with opposite vertices these two nodes. The optional argument of `\pnode` is an offset.

This code can be compiled with `pdflatex` if you set the `--enable-write18` switch for MiKTeX, `-shell-escape` for TeX Live and MacTeX.

Alternatively, do not load `auto-pst-pdf`, remove the `postscript` environment, and compile with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[english, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
  \begin{align}%
    \text{Equ} & ≡ \text{first line of RHS} +{} \\
                             & =+\;\text{second line of RHS} \\
    \pnode[-0.6em, 2.5ex]{A} & =\text{third line of RHS} + {} \\
                             & = +\; \text{fourth line of RHS} \pnode[0.8em, -1.5ex]{B}
  \end{align}
  \psframe[linejoin=1, linecolor=Coral](A)(B)
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added* : there seems to be problems with cross-references, which work well only in this version of the code, for use with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
 \usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pst-node}%
\usepackage{cleveref}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{align}%
 \text{Equ} & ≡ \text{first line of RHS} +{} \label{Equ1}\\
 & =+\;\text{second line of RHS} \\
\pnode[-0.6em, 2.5ex]{A}& =\text{third line of RHS} + {} \\
 & = +\; \text{fourth line of RHS}\label{Equ4}\pnode[0.8em, -1.5ex]{B}
 \psframe[linejoin=1](A)(B)
 \end{align}}
 \eqref{Equ1} and \cref{Equ4}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 2 follow-ups: 1) I am using the TeXworks editor with MiKTeX.  How does one set the `\--enable-write18\ ` switch for MiKTeX ?  2)  Is it possible to get equation numbering and use the `\label{}` function with this?  i.e., Can one get an equation number and label the fourth line?

Comment: For the second point: there's no problem for that (see my updated answer). Postscript acts as an overlay, and it has no dimension for TeX. To set `--enable-wite18`, go to `Edit -> Preferences-> Typesetting tab`. In the `Processing tools` window, select `pdflatex` to open `Tool Configuration ` and add the switch to the `Arguments` window.

Comment: I was able to get it to compile now, thank you.  I am still having trouble with the numbering starting over and referencing equations inside the `postscript` (see edits to question).

Comment: I have the same problem, and it does not seem to be linked to pstricks: I commented out all commands/environments that have something to do with it, and  I still have the same message over and over: `
LaTeX Warning: Reference `Equ1' on page 1 undefined on input line 49.LaTeX Warning: Reference `Equ2' on page 1 undefined on input line 49.` However my editor sees them.

Comment: I appreciate you troubleshooting the cross-references and I upvoted your answer.  My rep is too low for it to affect the public score count yet, though.