# Beamer, TikZ and step by step colored figure ending in PGF Math Error (divide by 0)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

I'm new to TikZ, and I'm trying to "animate" successive reading of values on the curve representing a mathematical function. The point is to achieve step by step visual enhancement to focus the care of my pupils.

The joint code compiles successfully, in this precise state. Uncomment lines 57 to 65, this compiles again (but if you start trying to compile directly with the lines 57 to 65 uncommented, it does not). Now uncomment the lines commented out twice, the code does not compile. I'm not enough skilled to understand why. I hope somebody will be able to explain why, and ideally find a workaround or a better way to achieve my goal. Thanks a lot in advance !

**[EDIT]**
The problem seems to be related to the angle options.

```
\draw [->, >=latex, very thick,color=blue!60] (xO) to[out=80,in=100] (yO) ;
\draw [->, >=latex, very thick,color=blue!60] (fxO) to[out=280,in=260] (fyO) ;
```

seems to make the thing works.
**[/EDIT]**

Regards,

natsirt

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,bending}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@textcolor}[3]{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\mathcolor}[2][green]{\relax\ifmmode\textcolor{#1}{#2}\else\textcolor{#1}{$#2$}\fi}

\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\mathcolor[red]{#1}}
\newcommand{\mg}[1]{\mathcolor{#1}}


\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

Bla \pause Bla \pause

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % Garder une figure stable avec Beamer / empêcher les dessins de sauter :
      % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61260/keep-a-fragmented-tikz-image-at-the-same-place-on-a-beamer-slide
      % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18704/how-can-i-fix-jumping-tikz-pictures-in-beamer
      \path[use as bounding box] (-5,-1) rectangle(6,5);
      % La graduation 1 horizontale
      \alt<4>{\draw [very thick, red] (1,-.75ex) -- node [below=.3ex] {$1$} (1,.75ex) ; }{\draw [very thick] (1,-.75ex) -- node [below=.3ex] {$1$} (1,.75ex) ; }
      \draw [very thick] (-.6ex,1) -- node [left=.3ex] {$1$} (.6ex,1) ;
      % Le grille
      \draw[help lines, color=gray, dashed] (-.2,-.2) grid (4.1,4.1);
      % Les axes
      \draw [-Stealth,ultra thick] (-.2,0)--(4.1,0) node[below] {$x$} ;
      \draw[-Stealth,ultra thick] (0,-.2)--(0,4.1) node[left] {$y$};
      % La courbe
      \draw [very thick, blue] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,4) (2.5,1) (4,2)} ;
      % Le nom de la courbe
      \node [blue] at (3.5,2) {$\mathscr{C}_f$} ;
      % Les points de la courbe
      \foreach \pos/\point in {(0,0)/O, (1,4)/A, (2.5,1)/B, (4,2)/C}{\draw node[green,label={[color=green,xshift=-.8ex,yshift=1ex]280:\point} ]%  below:$\point$]
       at \pos {\Large +}; }
      % Les affichages successifs
      % Le point O
      \uncover<3->{\node [right] at (-3,4) { $O( \tikz[baseline] { \node[anchor=base] (xO) { \alt<3>{\mg{0}}{$0$} } ; } \,; 
                                                 \tikz[baseline] { \node[anchor=base] (yO) { \alt<3>{\mr{0}}{$0$} } ; } 
                                              )$ } ;
                   \node [right] at (-3,3) { $f( \tikz[baseline] { \node[anchor=base] (fxO) { \alt<3>{\mg{0}}{$0$} } ; } ) =
                                                 \tikz[baseline] { \node[anchor=base] (fyO) { \alt<3>{\mr{0}}{$0$} } ; } 
                                             $ } ;
%                    \alt<3>{\draw [->, >=latex, very thick,color=blue!60] (xO) to[out=90,in=90] (yO) ;
%                            \draw [->, >=latex, very thick,color=blue!60] (fxO) to[out=270,in=270] (fyO) ;
%                            \draw [->, >=latex,very thick,dotted,color=green!80] (fxO) to[out=270,in=270] (0,-.3) ;
%                            \draw [->, >=latex,very thick,dotted,color=red!80] (fyO) to[out=0,in=180] (-.3,0) ;
%                            \draw node[green,label={[color=white,xshift=-.8ex,yshift=1ex,opacity=.75]280:O}] at (0,0) {\Large +} ;
%                            \node[green,below right] at (0,0) {$0$} ;
%                            \node[red,above left] at (0,0) {$0$} ; }
%                            {}
       }
% %        \uncover<4->{\draw [->, >=latex, very thick, dashed, color=blue!60] (1,0) -- (1,4) -- (0,4) ;
% %                    \node [right] at (-3,1) { $A( \tikz[baseline] { \node[anchor=base] (xA) { \alt<4>{\mg{1}}{$1$} } ; } \,; 
% %                                                  \tikz[baseline] { \node[anchor=base] (yA) { \alt<4>{\mr{4}}{$4$} } ; } 
% %                                               )$ } ;
% %                    \node [right] at (-3,0) { $f( \tikz[baseline]{ \node[anchor=base] (fxA) { \alt<3>{\mg{1}}{$1$} } ; } ) =
% %                                                  \tikz[baseline]{ \node[anchor=base] (fyA) { \alt<3>{\mr{4}}{$4$} } ; } 
% %                                              $ } ;
% %                    \alt<4>{\draw [->, >=latex, very thick,color=blue!60] (xA) to[out=90,in=90] (yA) ;
% %                            \draw [->, >=latex, very thick,color=blue!60] (fxA) to[out=270,in=270] (fyA) ; }
% %                           {}
% %        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Nesting `tikzpicture`s is known to cause trouble. I don't know whether it would resolve the issue here, but avoiding such nesting is good practice and will help avoid problems when practicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting `tikzpicture`s generally spells trouble. Sometimes it works, but you can't complain they didn't warn you if it breaks. Therefore, it should be considered only as a last resort. In this case, the code is safer and simpler if the `tikzmark` library is used to support the `\subnode{}{}` syntax. The first argument is the name. The second the content.

Note that information about the subnodes is always one compilation behind. Therefore, you may get errors on first compilation if, for example, using the distance between subnodes in a calculation because all subnodes will be, by default at one place. So you can easily end up dividing by zero which TikZ cannot (unsurprisingly) do.

Here's your example with subnodes. I've also updated to use the `\tikzset` syntax rather than the deprecated `\tikzstyle`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,bending,tikzmark}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@textcolor}[3]{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\mathcolor}[2][green]{\relax\ifmmode\textcolor{#1}{#2}\else\textcolor{#1}{$#2$}\fi}
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\mathcolor[red]{#1}}
\newcommand{\mg}[1]{\mathcolor{#1}}
\tikzset{% update syntax
  every picture/.append style = {remember picture},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Bla \pause Bla \pause
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Garder une figure stable avec Beamer / empêcher les dessins de sauter :
    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61260/keep-a-fragmented-tikz-image-at-the-same-place-on-a-beamer-slide
    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18704/how-can-i-fix-jumping-tikz-pictures-in-beamer
    \path[use as bounding box] (-5,-1) rectangle(6,5);
    % La graduation 1 horizontale
    \alt<4>{\draw [very thick, red] (1,-.75ex) -- node [below=.3ex] {$1$} (1,.75ex) ; }{\draw [very thick] (1,-.75ex) -- node [below=.3ex] {$1$} (1,.75ex) ; }
    \draw [very thick] (-.6ex,1) -- node [left=.3ex] {$1$} (.6ex,1) ;
    % Le grille
    \draw[help lines, color=gray, dashed] (-.2,-.2) grid (4.1,4.1);
    % Les axes
    \draw [-Stealth,ultra thick] (-.2,0)--(4.1,0) node[below] {$x$} ;
    \draw[-Stealth,ultra thick] (0,-.2)--(0,4.1) node[left] {$y$};
    % La courbe
    \draw [very thick, blue] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,4) (2.5,1) (4,2)} ;
    % Le nom de la courbe
    \node [blue] at (3.5,2) {$\mathscr{C}_f$} ;
    % Les points de la courbe
    \foreach \pos/\point in {(0,0)/O, (1,4)/A, (2.5,1)/B, (4,2)/C}{\draw node[green,label={[color=green,xshift=-.8ex,yshift=1ex]280:\point} ]%  below:$\point$]
      at \pos {\Large +}; }
    % Les affichages successifs
    % Le point O
    \uncover<3->{%
      \node [right] at (-3,4) { $O( \subnode{xO}{ \alt<3>{\mg{0}}{$0$} } \,;  \subnode{yO}{ \alt<3>{\mr{0}}{$0$} }  )$ } ;
    \node [right] at (-3,3) { $f( \subnode{fxO}{ \alt<3>{\mg{0}}{$0$} } ) = \subnode{fyO}{ \alt<3>{\mr{0}}{$0$} }  $ } ;
      \alt<3>{\draw [->, >=latex, very thick,color=blue!60] (xO) to[out=90,in=90] (yO) ;
        \draw [->, >=latex, very thick,color=blue!60] (fxO) to[out=270,in=270] (fyO) ;
        \draw [->, >=latex,very thick,dotted,color=green!80] (fxO) to[out=270,in=270] (0,-.3) ;
        \draw [->, >=latex,very thick,dotted,color=red!80] (fyO) to[out=0,in=180] (-.3,0) ;
        \draw node[green,label={[color=white,xshift=-.8ex,yshift=1ex,opacity=.75]280:O}] at (0,0) {\Large +} ;
        \node[green,below right] at (0,0) {$0$} ;
        \node[red,above left] at (0,0) {$0$} ; }
      {}
    }
    \uncover<4->{%
      \draw [->, >=latex, very thick, dashed, color=blue!60] (1,0) -- (1,4) -- (0,4) ;
      \node [right] at (-3,1) { $A(   \subnode{xA}{ \alt<4>{\mg{1}}{$1$} } \,; \subnode{yA}{ \alt<4>{\mr{4}}{$4$} } )$ } ;
      \node [right] at (-3,0) { $f( \subnode{fxA}{ \alt<3>{\mg{1}}{$1$} } ) = \subnode{fyA}{ \alt<3>{\mr{4}}{$4$} } $ } ;
      \alt<4>{%
        \draw [->, >=latex, very thick,color=blue!60] (xA) to[out=90,in=90] (yA) ;
        \draw [->, >=latex, very thick,color=blue!60] (fxA) to[out=270,in=270] (fyA) ;
      }
      {}
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: subnodes]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your welcome, your advice and your enhancements.

Comment: Anyway, that I should perhaps call a bug is still present (same error at compilation time). Modifying the angle (90 -> 91 or 89, 270 -> 269 or 271) solve the problem one more time. Perhaps the bug is related to my 3.0.0 version of PGF (it seems that the current stable one is the 3.0.1).

Comment: I have one last question about this picture - and it's not related to math error in PGF. I notice that the proper math spacing is not respected, either with my code or yours. Is there a way to recover a proper mathematical typesetting ? It's not that important, anyway...

Comment: @natsirt Sorry: I'm not sure. I suggest asking as a new question, with a link to this one for background. I don't typeset all that much maths myself, so I'm not at all competent in this area. (I typeset a little but with my editor's symbol panel open and a web browser on hand so I can search here for examples!)

Comment: @natsirt Just read your earlier comment. Yes, you'll still get an error on first compilation because the subnodes don't exist as far as TeX is concerned. However, you shouldn't get an error after the first run. Do you still get an error on second compilation? I don't get an error here.