# Tikz and Beamer: How to fix coordinate system to be the same on each slide?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Is it possible to make the coordinate system to be fixed on several slides in a beamer presentation? So that each point with the same coordinates in different `tikzpicture` environments on different slides is in exactly the same position in the resulting PDF?

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw (2,2) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How to modify this example, such that on both slides the circle at position (0,0) overlays?

Comment: This is hard to answer without an example illustrating what you mean exactly. At any rate, you can always place your TikZ picture relative to anchors of the `(current page)` coordinate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix jumping TikZ pictures in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18704/how-can-i-fix-jumping-tikz-pictures-in-beamer)

Comment: Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine: I don't think so, as I have different frame-ennvironments. So I cannot see how to make use of the answers of the denoted post.

Comment: You need to make sure that the `tikzpicture` occupies the same space (at least) vertically. This is achieved either by putting it in a box, or adding phantom elements in your `tikzpicture` to match them (in this case, adding something to the first `tikzpicture`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can set the `overlay` and `remember picture` option to the `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw (2,2) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With these options you have also access to the `current page` anchor, which allows for cool stuff like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,every node/.style={draw,minimum size=2.5cm,circle}]
\node [anchor=east] at (current page.east){};
\node [anchor=west] at (current page.west){};
\node [anchor=north] at (current page.north){};
\node [anchor=south] at (current page.south){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,every node/.style={draw,minimum size=2.5cm,circle}]
\node [anchor=east] at (current page.east){};
\node [anchor=west] at (current page.west){};
\node [anchor=north] at (current page.north){};
\node [anchor=south] at (current page.south){};
\node at (current page.center){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also fix the position using the `textpos` package and `textblock*` environment. This allows you to fix anything to a fixed coordinate position of the slide.

Do not that this works as an overlay and will therefore not interact typesetting-wise with stuff outside in inserted textblock.

A small working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

\begin{textblock*}{.0\textwidth}(13mm,77mm)

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x) {Here's a node};    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{textblock*}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```