# Avoid "jumps" in text between slides [Tikz]

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes, overlays

I created a diagram in beamer, but right now the text "jumps" when I flip the slide (When adding the "Primary outcomes in survey" bullet point). I'd like the text to stay stable. Could someone help me please? Thank you!

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} 
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}
  \usecolortheme{default}
  \usefonttheme{default}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bbold} %indicator function
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic} %% Maybe get rid of, shows when going to uncover

\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{comment}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{invisible}{gray}{1}
\definecolor{blue(pigment)}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}
\definecolor{ceruleanblue}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}
\definecolor{indigo(dye)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.25, 0.42}
\definecolor{kellygreen}{rgb}{0.3, 0.73, 0.09}
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{005073}
\definecolor{test}{RGB}{0,136,196}%{106,168,79}%{48,159,169}%{48,149,193}%{3,168,158}%%{69,160,199}%{37,132,214}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=Blue}%ceruleanblue}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=test}

%%%% TIKZ STUFF
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Overlays

\newcounter{jumping}
\resetcounteronoverlays{jumping}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    stop jumping/.style={
        execute at end picture={%
            \stepcounter{jumping}%
            \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
                \noexpand\jump@setbb{\the\value{jumping}}{\noexpand\pgfpoint{\the\pgf@picminx}{\the\pgf@picminy}}{\noexpand\pgfpoint{\the\pgf@picmaxx}{\the\pgf@picmaxy}}
            },
            \csname jump@\the\value{jumping}@maxbb\endcsname
            \path (\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y);
            \csname jump@\the\value{jumping}@minbb\endcsname
            \path (\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y);
        },
    }
}
\def\jump@setbb#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{jump@#1@maxbb}{%
        \expandafter\gdef\csname jump@#1@maxbb\endcsname{#3}%
    }{%
    \csname jump@#1@maxbb\endcsname
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    #3
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{max(\pgf@x,\pgf@xa)}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{max(\pgf@y,\pgf@ya)}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname jump@#1@maxbb\endcsname{\noexpand\pgfpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}%
}
\@ifundefined{jump@#1@minbb}{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname jump@#1@minbb\endcsname{#2}%
}{%
\csname jump@#1@minbb\endcsname
\pgf@xa=\pgf@x
\pgf@ya=\pgf@y
#2
\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{min(\pgf@x,\pgf@xa)}%
\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{min(\pgf@y,\pgf@ya)}%
\expandafter\xdef\csname jump@#1@minbb\endcsname{\noexpand\pgfpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}%
}
}
\makeatother



%%%%%% END TIKZ STUFF
% Continue MD stuff
\newenvironment{itemize1}{\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{10pt}\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}}{\end{itemize}}
\newenvironment{itemize2}{\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{5pt}\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}}{\end{itemize}}
\newenvironment{enumerate1}{\begin{enumerate}\setlength{\itemsep}{10pt}\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{enumerate2}{\begin{enumerate}\setlength{\itemsep}{5pt}\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}

% Wider slide
\newcommand\Wider[2][3em]{%
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+#1\relax}
  \raggedright#2
  \end{minipage}%
  }%
}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
   \raisebox{5pt}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\hfill\makebox[10pt]{\scriptsize\insertframenumber}}}}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{   
        every picture/.style={remember picture,baseline},
        every node/.style={anchor=base,align=center,outer sep=-1pt},
        every path/.style={thick},
    }
    
    \newcommand\marktopleft[1]{%
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
        \node (marker-#1-a) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
    }
    
    \newcommand\tikzmark[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
\node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=2.5pt] (#1){#2};%
}


    \newcommand\markbottomright[1]{%
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
        \node (marker-#1-b) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=3pt]
        \node[draw=red,rounded corners,fit=(marker-#1-a.north west) (marker-#1-b.south east)] {};%
    }   
    \usetikzlibrary {positioning}   


\begin{frame}[label=data_collection]{Overview of data collection}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[stop jumping]
  
  % Main
  \node<2->[draw, text width=4.15em, minimum height=4em, text centered, rounded corners] (ArgumentA) at (1,0) { \footnotesize Baseline beliefs};
  \node<2>[draw, text width=4.15em, minimum height=4em, text centered, rounded corners,fill=black!20] (ArgumentA) at (1,0) { \footnotesize Baseline beliefs};
  \node<3->[draw, text width=4.5em, minimum height=4em, text centered, rounded corners] (ArgumentB) at (3.25,0) {\footnotesize Information treatment};
  \node<3>[draw, text width=4.5em, minimum height=4em, text centered, rounded corners,fill=black!20] (ArgumentB) at (3.25,0) {{\visible<1->{\footnotesize Information treatment}}};
    \node<4->[draw, text width=4.15em, minimum height=4em, text centered, rounded corners] (ArgumentC) at (5.5,0) {{\visible<1->{\footnotesize Endline Beliefs}}};
    \node<4>[draw, text width=4.15em, minimum height=4em, text centered, rounded corners,fill=black!20] (ArgumentC) at (5.5,0) {{\visible<1->{\footnotesize Endline Beliefs}}};
    \node<5->[draw, text width=4.5em, minimum height=4em, text centered, rounded corners] (ArgumentD) at (8.3,-0.25) {{\visible<1->{\footnotesize Outcomes}}};
    \node<5>[draw, text width=4.5em, minimum height=4em, text centered, rounded corners,fill=black!20] (ArgumentD) at (8.3,-0.25) {{\visible<1->{\footnotesize Outcomes}}};
    \node<6->[] (ArgumentE) at (6.8, -2) {{\visible<1->{\footnotesize Endline Choices}}};
    \node<6->[] (ArgumentF) at (6.8, -0.3) {};
    
   
  
       %% Measure outcomes
            \node<5>[draw, text width=\textwidth, minimum height=4em, text centered, rounded corners, draw=invisible] (ExplA) at (4,-1.25) {
        %For all treatment and subset of control (to avoid priming), ask: 

                \begin{itemize}
                    \bigskip
                    \bigskip
                    \item Primary outcomes in Resource Center
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item \alert{Job training}: complete intake form for employment training services 
                            \item \alert{Math skills}: sign up for online math and computer tutoring 
                            %\item Sign up for email about savings account (secondary outcome)
                        \end{itemize}
                \smallskip
                \item[]
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item[]
                        \item[]
                    \end{itemize}                \end{itemize}
        };

    \node<6>[draw, text width=\textwidth, minimum height=4em, anchor=west, draw=invisible] (ExplA) at (-3,-3.2) {
     
          \begin{itemize}
               \bigskip
               \bigskip
               \bigskip
                \item Primary outcomes in Resource Center
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item \alert{Job training}: complete intake form for employment training services 
                        \item \alert{Math skills}: sign up for online math and computer tutoring 
                    \end{itemize}
                \smallskip
                \item Primary outcomes in survey
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item \alert{Tutoring}: decide between \$50 cash and \$300 tutoring if win
                        \item \alert{Career book}: \$40 cash or (\$35 + Career Prep for Teens book, worth \$12)
                    \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
           
          
            };

    \node<7>[draw, text width=\textwidth, minimum height=4em, anchor=west, draw=invisible] (ExplA) at (-3,-3.2) {
     
          \begin{itemize}
               \bigskip
               \bigskip
               \bigskip
                \item Secondary outcomes
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Savings: sign up for email about ABLE savings account (Resource Center)
                        \item Employment and college plans (survey)
                    \end{itemize}
                \smallskip
                \item Medium- and long-run outcomes
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Education (e.g., attendance), use of job training services, employment outcomes
                    \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
           
          
            };

 
  \draw<3->[->,draw=test] (ArgumentA) to (ArgumentB);
  \draw<4->[->,draw=test] (ArgumentB) to (ArgumentC);
  \draw<5->[->,draw=test] (ArgumentC) to (ArgumentD);
  \draw<6->[->, draw=test] (ArgumentE) to (ArgumentF);
  
    \draw<1-> [rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed,thick](-.25,-1.25) rectangle (7,1);
  \draw<1-> (3.25,1.25) node {\footnotesize \emph{Day 1: Web Survey}};
  \draw<5-> (8.3,1.25) node {\footnotesize \emph{Day 2 onwards}};
  
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should really not resort to copy&paste for your slide text. Instead, make use of `\only` or `\visible` to limit what text is visible on what slide. That will probably also make it easier to avoid jumping text

Comment: Why did you delete your previous version (including my answer) and re-ask it? Self-deleted question, especially one with negative score, will contribute to a possible question ban.

Comment: ... and don't you get an error from `\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}`?

Comment: Possibly of use: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18704/86

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really recommend you take to heart what I already wrote in my comment: Don't use C&P but instead leverage the `\visible` and (where appropriate) the `\only` commands.

If you keep everything together without C&P you'll have a much easier time arriving at a consistent (non-jumping) layout.

I went ahead and shrunk your example to the essential parts and provide you with a jump-free (parametrized) version of your jumpy slide. I hope this gets the idea across of what I did to avoid any jumping. As I did not see any need for the list to be inside the `tikzpicture`, I moved it out of there.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} 

\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[label=data_collection]{Overview of data collection}
        \def\horizontalSep{0.5cm}
        \def\verticalSep{0.5cm}
        \def\nodeWidth{4.5em}
        \def\nodeHeight{4.5em}
        \def\nodeInnerSep{0.5em}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\nodeTextWidth{\nodeWidth - 2*\nodeInnerSep}

        \tikzset{
            rounded corners,
            every node/.style = {
                right,
                draw,
                minimum height = \nodeHeight,
                text width = \nodeTextWidth,
                text centered,
                outer sep = 0pt,
                inner sep = \nodeInnerSep,
            },
        }

        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[gray, dashed] (0,0) rectangle ++({3*\nodeWidth + 4*\horizontalSep}, {\nodeHeight + 2*\verticalSep});

                \visible<2->{
                    \node (A) at ({\horizontalSep}, {\verticalSep + 0.5*\nodeHeight}) {test};
                }
                \visible<3->{
                    \node (B) at ({2*\horizontalSep + \nodeWidth}, {\verticalSep + 0.5*\nodeHeight}) {test2};
                }
                \visible<4->{
                    \node (C) at ({3*\horizontalSep + 2*\nodeWidth}, {\verticalSep + 0.5*\nodeHeight}) {test3};
                }
                \visible<5->{
                    % Add an extra sep for this one
                    \node (D) at ({(4 + 1)*\horizontalSep + 3*\nodeWidth}, {\verticalSep + 0.5*\nodeHeight}) {test4};
                }

                \visible<6->{
                    \path (C.south east) ++(\horizontalSep, {-2*\verticalSep}) node[draw=none,inner sep=0pt,minimum height=0pt,text width=3cm,below] (E) {Endline Choices};
                }

                \draw<3->[->, blue] (A) -- (B);
                \draw<4->[->, blue] (B) -- (C);
                \draw<5->[->, blue] (C) -- (D);
                \draw<6->[->, blue] (E.north) -- ++(0, {2*\verticalSep + 0.5*\nodeHeight});
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item<5-> Primary outcomes in Resource Center
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Job training: complete intake form for employment training services
                    \item Math skills: sign up for online math and computer tutoring
                \end{itemize}
            \item<6-> Primary outcomes in survey
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Tutoring: decide between \$50 cash and \$300 tutoring if win
                    \item Career book: \$40 cash or (\$35 + Career Prep for Teens book, worth \$12)
                \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As already said in [the answer to your question, which you deleted as soon as you got an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666119/avoid-jumps-in-text-in-a-diagram-tikz/666123#666123):

You can use the `overlay-beamer-styles` library. This library also allows you to specify on which overlays a node should be filled:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} 

\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{005073}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=Blue} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=data_collection]
  \frametitle{Overview of data collection}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  
  % Main
  \node[visible on={<2->}, fill=black!20, fill on=<2>, draw, text width=4.15em, minimum height=4em, text centered, rounded corners, font=\footnotesize] (ArgumentA) at (1,0) {Baseline beliefs};
  \node[visible on={<3->}, fill=black!20, fill on=<3>, draw, text width=4.5em, minimum height=4em, text centered, rounded corners, font=\footnotesize] (ArgumentB) at (3.25,0) {Information treatment};  
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for deleting the question , I'm not too familiar using this and I saw that my code had some mistakes and my question was not so clear so I thought that it would be better to re-ask it.

Comment: @Giane In the future just edit. It is such a waste of time if one writes and answer and then the OP just deletes it with the question :(

Comment: Will do, sorry for the inconvenience!