# Avoid jumps from overlays in beamer in TikZ picture inside `adjustbox` environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I have a TikZ picture that is animated. Unfortunately, that causes jumps in the content, as the centering is apparently not considering the animation.

I resize the picture with an adjustbox, so it fits the page nicely.

Is there a way to avoid page jumps in such a setup?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Demo}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=40pt]
            \node<+-> [draw] (one) {One};
            \node<+-> [draw,below=of one] (two) {Two};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Potentially scaling elements which contain text is not the best of ideas, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text

Comment: Thanks for the link. Currently, the approach seems to be the most forward one, though. That way, it can be easily ensured that all content fits the page. As long as the scaling is not applied with too high factors, I think that should be a good tradeoff. Still, it is good to be aware of the side effects!

Comment: Even if the scaling factors are not too big, you get a mixture of many different sizes in your presentation. This can make it more like a ransom letter than a thought through presentation.

Comment: You might find this question helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18704/86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the jumping if the elements are present (but not visible) on all overlays, e.g. with the `overlay-beamer-styles` library:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Demo}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=40pt]
            \node[visible on=<+->] [draw] (one) {One};
            \node[draw,below=of one,visible on=<+->] (two) {Two};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I wasn't aware of that library! Thanks so much. Apparently, this requires a specific format for the overlays (inside the brackets)? I am fine with that, just curious.

Comment: @clel Almost all of the normal beamer overlay syntax will work for the `overlay-beamer-styles` library (there are some edge cases, but unlikely you will run into them)

Comment: Hm, the `\node<+-> [draw] (one) {One};` syntax from my MWE didn't work for me, as that still had the jumps. I also looked for documentation of the library, but couldn't find any, unfortunately. If you have hints to both problems, that'd be very appreciated.

Comment: @clel You can get the doc if you run `texdoc aobs` or from https://texdoc.org/serve/aobs-tikz/0 if you don't have the docs installed

Comment: @clel With `\node<+-> ` the node is not present on earlier overlays. With `visible on=<+->` it is present, just not visible

Comment: Docs: Are you sure? I also found that package, but it states, that it makes use of the library; so sounds like it is not the library doc itself. Also, reading further through the docs didn't give any helpful information about the library.

Comment: The library is part of the package. Basically everything in the doc reveres to the library. The package version is just a wrapper which loads tikz and the library.

Comment: Really? Then the options that the library provides (like `visible on=`) seem not documented well.

Comment: Makes sense that this option then doesn't cause page jumps. Alright. I just checked and it seems that the library provides the option, so basically both are needed in combination to make it work as intended.